# SQLAlchemy Multi Table & Foreign Key Join

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Got four tables; `users`, `company`, `company_branch` and `users_branch`. Users are people belonging to company. A company has got branches and a user can belong to a single branch at any given time. However, the users_branch table exists to keep track of the history of changing from one branch to another. E.g. To get the current branch of a user with id 1, one would run a `SELECT company_id, company_branch_id FROM users_branch WHERE user_id = 1 ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1`.

The challange I have is that am not able to figure out the correct not SQLAlchemy ORM syntax but also SQL raw to get list of users in a certain company at a given time and do so while returning the `users_id, users_email_address, company_id, company_name, compancy_branch_id and company_branch_name` for each entry. The queries I've tried so far either return nothing or they return repeated values in the users_branch wheareas I only want the latest branch for each user

[Here is the link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f47ba) to the sqlfiddle sample postgresql database. In SQAlchemy the models are `Users, Company, CompanyBranch, UsersBranch` as seen below:

```
class Users(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    email_address = Column(String(70), nullable=False, unique=True)

class Company(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'company'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    created_at = Column(DateTime, server_default=text('NOW()'), nullable=False)
    created_by = Column(ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable=False)
    company_name = Column(String(100), nullable=False, unique=True)

class CompanyBranch(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'company_branch'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    created_at = Column(DateTime, server_default=text('NOW()'), nullable=False)
    created_by = Column(ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable=False)
    company_id = Column(ForeignKey('company.id'), nullable=False)
    branch_name = Column(String(100), nullable=False, unique=True)

class UsersBranch(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users_branch'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    created_at = Column(DateTime, server_default=text('NOW()'), nullable=False)
    created_by = Column(ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable=False)
    user_id = Column(ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable=False)
    company_id = Column(ForeignKey('company.id'), nullable=False)
    company_branch_id = Column(ForeignKey('company_branch.id'), nullable=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, let me start by saying your schema is a little denormalized. `users_branch.company_id` is not necessary because `users_branch.company_branch_id` can also give you the `company_id`. There may be a good reason for it, but it might be adding some confusion here.

This is tricky because of the `users_branch` table. It essentially requires grouping by `user_id` and selecting the row with the max `created_at`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (users_branch.user_id)
  *
FROM
  users
  JOIN users_branch ON users.id = users_branch.user_id
  JOIN company_branch ON users_branch.company_branch_id = company_branch.id
  JOIN company ON company_branch.company_id = company.id
WHERE users_branch.created_at < [some date]
ORDER BY users_branch.user_id, users_branch.created_at DESC;
```

This doesn't map well to the SQLAlchemy ORM, though.

Comment: The `company_id` being included in the `users_branch` table is intentional for querying purposes. I'll test your code and report back. Thanks.

Comment: Your query didn't work as expected mostly because you are giving a `created_at < 'some_date'`. The result needed should be such that if a user has changed branches five times meaning they have 5 entries in the users_branch table, the query should return only the latest entry. See the example I gave in the post of `order_by created_at DESC limit 1` which would work when getting the result for one user. However now we want the latest entry for all users of a specific company.

Comment: @lukik Does it not return the latest one before a certain date?

Comment: It does but it returns even older branches where a user was once "located". I searched on how to use the SQL Max function and I came up with an answer which I've posted and seems to work for both SQL and SQLAlchemy

Comment: Having the option to specify list of users at a particular point in time would be much more robust. Your code would allow me to ask a question like "show me the user's who were in this branch at a specific time"... which would also cover my use case of getting the latest user branches coz then all I'd need to pass is `created_at < time.now()`. Only issue I have is that when I run your code to show the current users in a specific branch it shows users who are no longer in that branch so I think your code could do with some further tweaking?

Comment: @lukik You can't just do `WHERE users_branch.created_at < ... AND company_branch.id = 1`. You need to wrap it in a subquery or the results won't be correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've nailed what I needed. The following raw SQL code seems to give me the proper answer of returning only the current branch where user's are. Took me a while but I also figured out the SQlAlchemy equivalent. I'll leave it here as an answer for a while and see if anyone else can tune it further.

**Raw SQL**

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (users_branch.user_id) users.email_address, company.id as company_id, company.company_name, company_branch.id AS company_branch_id, company_branch.branch_name
FROM
  users
  JOIN users_branch ON users.id = users_branch.user_id
  JOIN company_branch ON users_branch.company_branch_id = company_branch.id
  JOIN company ON company_branch.company_id = company.id
WHERE users_branch.created_at in (SELECT max(users_branch.created_at) FROM users_branch GROUP BY users_branch.user_id) AND 
users_branch.company_id = 1 AND
users_branch.company_branch_id = 3
```

**SQL Alchemy**

```
query = session.query(Users.id.label('user_id'), Users.email_address, Company.id.label('company_id'), Company.company_name,
CompanyBranch.id.label("company_branch_id"), CompanyBranch.branch_name).distinct(UsersBranch.user_id). \
join(UsersBranch, and_(Users.id == UsersBranch.user_id)). \
join(CompanyBranch, and_(UsersBranch.company_branch_id == CompanyBranch.id)).\
join(Company, and_(CompanyBranch.company_id == Company.id)).\
filter(UsersBranch.created_at.in_(session.query(func.max(UsersBranch.created_at)).group_by(UsersBranch.user_id))).\
filter(UsersBranch.company_id == 1).\
filter(UsersBranch.company_branch_id == 3)
```

Comment: But this doesn't give you the list of users with their branches at a particular point in time, just the very latest. It's also slightly more fragile because it assumes that `created_at` between users are unique (which it usually is, but is not a universal assumption that you can make).

Comment: Your right. Having the option to specify list of users at a particular point in time would be much more robust. See comment on your answer